# Xcode 7 UI Testing XCUIElementQuery Randomly Not Updating Properly

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UI Test that dismisses an alert, checks to see if the alert had been dismissed (if not it attempts to dismiss it again) and then continues on with the rest of the test.

Most of the time the test passes just fine, but sometimes seemingly randomly (though more often in the simulator on a machine with older hardware), the test will do the following:

- check for the alert
- tap on the button that dismisses the alert
- the alert is dismissed
- check for the alert (and still find it - I have logged the query at this point and it is indeed finding the same alert that was just dismissed)
- attempt to tap the button that dismisses the alert
- complain that it can't find the alert and fail

A couple of notes:

- I have not, as of yet, observed this behaviour when stepping through the test with the debugger.
- Forcing the test to wait a bit after dismissing the alert (using things like usleep()) can still cause this behaviour.

Why is the query still finding the alert after it has been dismissed? Why is this behaviour seemingly random?

Comment: Interesting... So it seems this issue is stemming from the fact that the alert was being shown at the same time as the keyboard. I have modified the test to dismiss the keyboard before the alert is shown, and the test no longer appears to be failing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried interacting with the alert via a [UI Interruption](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCTestCase.html#//api/name/addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription:handler:) handler?

```
addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Alert") { (alert) -> Bool in
    alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
    return true
}
```

Comment: This only seems to work for system alerts - the alert in question is created by the application.

Comment: I just verified that this works for user-created `UIAlertController`s. Did you make sure to add the interruption handler *before* the alert appears?

Comment: Hmmm. The alert is a `UIAlertView`, not a `UIAlertController`. I suppose this could be an issue since it is technically deprecated.

Comment: I just tried my same code with a `UIAlertView` on an iPhone 4s simulator running iOS 9 and it still worked. Perhaps you could post more of your code to a gist and/or we can [continue this conversation in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96475/xcode-ui-testing)?